# How do i set a variable again in a loop

Tags: c++, variables

I'm new to c++ and have a question with variables

```
int main() {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int e;
    int parafechar;
    int loop = 10;
    while(loop==10) {
        cout<< "Coloque a mensal 1\n";
        cin >> a;
        cout<< "Coloque a mensal 2\n";
        cin >> e;
        cout <<"Coloque a nota do cnem\n";
        cin >> b;
        cout << "Coloque a media dos trabalhos\n";
        cin >> c;
        if(a>b) {
            cout << "A media e : " << a*0.5 + b*0.25 + c*0.25<<endl;
        } else {
            cout << "A media e : " << e*0.5 + b*0.25 + c*0.25<<endl;
        }
        cout << "aperte uma tecla para fechar o programa\n";
        cin >> parafechar;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

after the last line i want the code to run again and all the variables to be set again but the program goes on endless, what should i do ?
( the program is in portuguese but it calculate grades)
thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. Should the program never finish? Because that is what the code is doing and you are saying "i want the code to run again". If you remove the `while` loop, then it will stop running again.

Comment: use for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {....}

Comment: Why don't use a/4 + b/4...?

Answer (score 1):

> after the last line i want the code to run again and all the variables to be set again but the program goes on endless, what should i do?

Change the check in `while` and change the value of `loop` so that it will eventually meet the condition to stop the loop.

```
while(loop > 0) {

   // Do your stuff...

   // Decrement loop. It will eventually become zero
   // and the conditional in the while statement will fail.
   --loop;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
while (loop==10)
```

will give always true because the value of loop is not changing trough out the program.
What i can understand is , You want to iterate your loop 10 Times. So in this case you should write :

```
while (loop>0){

// your code of calculating grades

loop--; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the loop to be executed 10 times , you can do:

```
int loop = 10;   
while (loop--) {
  //do something
}
```